# Why isn't Chef showing logs from my custom handler?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to understand Chef's handlers better and with some reading over [Chef's documentation](https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html) and some blog posts, I have this basic custom handler set up.

This is at the start of my recipe

```
chef_handler 'SimpleReport::UpdatedResources' do
  source "handler_test.rb"
  action :enable
end
```

---

This is the handler ie, `handler_test.rb`

```
require 'chef/log'
require 'chef/handler'

module SimpleReport
  class UpdatedResources < Chef::Handler

    def report
      if run_status.updated_resources
        Chef::Log.info "Resources updated this run:"
        run_status.updated_resources.each {|r| Chef::Log.info "#{r.to_s}"}
      else
        Chef::Log.info "No Resources updated this run!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm running Chef Zero, with log level set to info. Chef recognizes and registers the handler:

```
* chef_handler[SimpleReport::UpdatedResources] action enable
   - disable SimpleReport::UpdatedResources as a report handler
   - disable SimpleReport::UpdatedResources as a exception handler
   - load SimpleReport::UpdatedResources from handler_test.rb
   - enable chef_handler[SimpleReport::UpdatedResources] as a report handler
   - enable chef_handler[SimpleReport::UpdatedResources] as a exception handler
```

yet at the end of the run, there's no report from the handler:

```
Running handlers:
  - SimpleReport::UpdatedResources
Running handlers complete
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dropped by the Chef community slack and [was told that Chef may enable the](https://chefcommunity.slack.com/archives/general/p1481889776002585) formatter and show the formatter output if Chef is run interactively(as determined by the presence of a [TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for))

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere but is [present in the code](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/chef-config/lib/chef-config/config.rb#L318-L323). To get around this, you can use the `--force-logger` option to ensure it uses the log output instead of the formatted output, or pass the `-L log-file-name` to log the results to a file